# Can the resize element (--webkit-resizer) have different width than the scrollbar track?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, textarea

I am working on an app with a custom scrollbar (which is thiner than the normal one). We have several resizable `textarea`s that are supposed to be resizable, but also display a scrollbar if the text doesn't fit so the user is aware that the text is longer.

If the scrollbar is visible (so if there is overflow) we should use the custom scrollbar (the thin one).

The main issue is that, when the scrollbar is there, the resize element is also smaller.

I tried different approaches (customising the scrollbar in different ways, customise the resize  element, add a positioned absolute element to indicate the resize area) but nothing worked properly.

The closest I got was with an absolute positioned element (with `pointer-events: none`). But the resize area is still the same, so there are visible differences in the area you can actually use the resize (between an textarea with scrollbar vs one without).
I also tried to at least make the default resize element smaller but that didn't seem to work either.

I am aware that the customisation of the resize element (and scrollbars in general) is limited and browers / OS dependent, but I am looking for any relevant ideea that could help with this.

Bellow is a minimal reproducible example. Is there any way to at least have them on the same size?  Any relevant help is appreciated.

```css
div { 
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 350px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
    position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<h1>The resize Property</h1>

<div>
  <p>this is a resizable element.</p>
  <p>In the bottom right corner there is the element to resize.</p>
  <p>If the the container becomes smaller than this, the element to resize (the resize indicator or the `::-webkit-resizer` element ) will automatically shrink. If it will be resized to fit all content again, the element to resize will return to it's original size </p>
  
</div>
```